# How to access hashes whose keys are arrays in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am trying to access data that has a structure like this (the status of each user on specific dates). As you can see, the hash keys are all arrays. This data has been retrieved from the DB using `group_by`.

```rb
data = {
  ["active", "Rick"]=>["2019-07-09", "2019-07-10"],
  ["active", "Morty"]=>["2019-07-09", "2019-07-10"],
  ["active", "Summer"]=>["2019-07-09", "2019-07-10"],
  ["inactive", "Rick"]=> ["2019-07-01", "2019-07-02", "2019-07-03"],
  ["inactive", "Summer"]=>["2019-07-15"]
}
```

I would rather have this data be a nested hash, like below. Is there a way to restructure it?

I know that each item in the hash can be accessed like this: `data[["active", "Summer"]]`. I tried doing something like `data[["active", "*"]]` (to get the active status data for all users) but this did not work.

```rb
data = {
  "active"=>{
    "Rick"=>["2019-07-09", "2019-07-10"],
    "Morty"=>["2019-07-09", "2019-07-10"],
    "Summer"=>["2019-07-09", "2019-07-10"]
  },
  "inactive"=>{
    "Rick"=>["2019-07-01", "2019-07-02", "2019-07-03"],
    "Summer"=>["2019-07-15"]
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right - fixed the code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
new_data = {}
data.each do |k, v|
  new_data[k.first] ||= []
  new_data[k.first] << { k.last => v}
end
```

But if you are in control of the db/query, perhaps it is better to retrieve your data from the db in the right format right away if possible.

Comment: Or more compactly: `data.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = { } }) { |(k, v), h| h[k.first][k.last] = v }`. Assuming they want nested hashes of course.

Comment: @Smek Also, I agree that it's better to retrieve the DB in the correct format instead of mutating it later. I raised a separate question because I am struggling with this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56948097/11249670

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this -

```
    new_data = { 'active' => [], 'inactive' => [] }
    data.each do |key, value|
      if key.first == 'active'
        new_data['active'] << { key.last => value }
      elsif key.first == 'inactive'
        new_data['inactive'] << { key.last => value }
      end
    end
```