# How to retrieve relational data from Rails DB in the form of a nested hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sorting

In my Rails DB, I have these tables:

- `users`
- `statuses` (let's say their names include `active` and `inactive`),
- `status_records` for each date for each user to show their status (e.g. `date: '2019-07-09', user: User.first, status: Status.find_by(name: 'active')`

I would like to retrieve data in a nested hash like this:

```rb
data = {
  "active"=>{
    "Rick"=>["2019-07-09", "2019-07-10"],
    "Morty"=>["2019-07-09", "2019-07-10"],
    "Summer"=>["2019-07-09", "2019-07-10"]
  },
  "inactive"=>{
    "Rick"=>["2019-07-01", "2019-07-02", "2019-07-03"],
    "Summer"=>["2019-07-15"]
  }
}
```

So far, I've gotten this far.

```rb
data = StatusRecord.joins(:status, :user)
  .where(statuses: {name: ['active', 'inactive']})
  .select('status_records.date, statuses.name as status, users.name as username')
  .group_by(|record| [record.status, record.username])
```

The above brings me to the data structure below, but as I wrote previously, this is not exactly what I want (I want to organise the data as a nested hash).

```rb
data = {
  ["active", "Rick"]=>["2019-07-09", "2019-07-10"],
  ["active", "Morty"]=>["2019-07-09", "2019-07-10"],
  ["active", "Summer"]=>["2019-07-09", "2019-07-10"],
  ["inactive", "Rick"]=> ["2019-07-01", "2019-07-02", "2019-07-03"],
  ["inactive", "Summer"]=>["2019-07-15"]
}
```

Is there a way to rewrite this query so that I can get the data in the desired structure?

Comment: Which database do you use? MySQL? PostgreSQL? Or something else?

Comment: @Smek Didn't see this in time - I use Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there!

You can use [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_object) to fix your output a bit.

```
data = StatusRecord.joins(:status, :user)
  .where(statuses: {name: ['active', 'inactive']})
  .select('status_records.date, statuses.name as status, users.name as username')
  .each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Hash.new {|hh,kk| hh[kk] = [] } }) do |sr, hash|
    hash[sr.status][sr.username] << sr.date
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure sql solution **please note this only works with MySQL 5.7+** but perhaps there are similar solutions for other databases.

```
    SELECT JSON_OBJECT(s.name, GROUP_CONCAT(srs.record)) AS record
    FROM statuses AS s
         INNER JOIN (SELECT JSON_OBJECT(u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(date)) AS record, status_id
                     FROM status_records AS sr
                              JOIN users u ON u.id = sr.user_id GROUP BY
                          u.id,
                          status_id) srs ON srs.status_id = s.id
    GROUP BY s.id;
```

You would be able to parse the resulting record column of each row into a hash.